# executing Spark project

Tags: maven, spark-java

I am new in developing with Spark. I have a program just with a main method ,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
                   final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(
                        SparkHomework.class, "/");

                Spark.get(new Route("/") {
                    @Override
                    public Object handle(final Request request,
                                         final Response response) {
                        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                        try {


    Template helloTemplate =      configuration.getTemplate("answer.ftl");

                           Map<String, String> answerMap = new   
HashMap<String, String>();
                            answerMap.put("answer", createAnswer());

                            helloTemplate.process(answerMap, writer);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error("Failed", e);
                            halt(500);
                       }
                        return writer;
                    }
                });
            }
```

but When I ran this program I got following error:

And also , when I compile this form with Maven, I get following error:

```
 [WARNING] The POM for com.sparkjava:spark-core:jar:1.1.1 is missing, no dependency information available:

    Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51871', transport: 'socket'
    Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
        at spark.Spark$1.run(Spark.java:303)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51871', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Is your pom.xml having this entry ? if not add it <dependency>
 <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: yes , my pom file is implemented as below code: